# JAXB unmarshalling to managed JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb

I've got a managed JPA entity (with subentities as well). Some of the fields of given entities should be filled by unmarshalling an XML file retrieved from another datasource. The problem is that JAXB will not unmarshall the XML into existing objects but create a new object instead. What is the simplest way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unmarshalling into an existing JPA object, you should use the JPA `merge` operation to merge the state of the detached entity into a persistence context.

```
public void updateEmployee(Employee detachedEntity) {
   Employee managedEntity = entityManager.merge(detachedEntity);
   // do further operations on managedEntity and not detachedEntity
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you are using JPA 2.1 then you could leverage entity graphs for this use case.

Comment: Ok, let's make this clear:
I have a class with fields A and B (and let's say ID). In one DB the only stored field is A (and ID). In another DB I've got an xml file with ID and B field. The A field does not exist in the xml. Will the merge not result in overwriting the value of A to null?

Comment: Just to clarify - I don't want to store the B field at all, so the merge method is not the proper way to solve the problem